# Pycharm says No module named 'kivy' when I try to import it eventhough Kivy works on IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

When I try to import kivy,it says: No module named 'kivy'

[image]

On IDE it works. I will add a screenshot so that you could have a better look and maybe help me solve that problem.

Comment: Do you mean that it works in IDLE?

Comment: What is your SDK configuration in PyCharm?

Comment: When you go to pycharm -> file -> preferences -> project: <project_name> ->Project Interpreter what does it say?

Comment: Python 3.7 (hellokivy). hellokivy is the project name  @PeterH

Comment: Yes, id does work on IDLE and I don't really know wha SDK mean if you explain more @Code-Apprentice

Comment: How did you install kivy? pip? What operating system are you on? @omarwael27

Comment: Yes, I used pip on windows. The installation was successful but for some reason it doesn't seem to work on Pycharm. @PeterH

Comment: In PyCharm, go to File -> Project Structure in the menu (or press Alt-Ctrl-Shift-S). Then click on Project in the left hand menu. What is selected under "Project SDK"?

Comment: I didn't find something called project structure in the file menu, but I managed to import kivy by copying the kivy folder to the venv folder in the Pycharm project as it wasn't there. It imports kivy but it doesn't look to work properly. For example it says Unable to get a text provider and things like that. The problem is that it shuld be in venv naturally from the beginning but that's not the case. Do you have any solution to make it work properly? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Thank you @Code-Apprentice for helping me.

Comment: Thank you @PeterH as well for helping.

Comment: "The problem is that it shuld be in venv naturally from the beginning" Nothing is naturally in venv. You have to install it.

Comment: " I managed to import kivy by copying the kivy folder to the venv folder" This is not the correct way to install packages. Instead you should use pip or the tools in PyCharm to install it. If you use pip from the command line, you need to first activate the virtual environment.

Comment: I did install it and it now works fine. Thank you so much @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using a virtual environment in PyCharm and using the global environment or a different virtual environment in IDLE. You need to install kivy in the virtual environment you are using for it to work. There are several ways to do this. One is to position the worker in the import statement then press Alt-Enter. This should give a popup menu with an option to install kivy. Use the arrow keys to navigate to this option if necessary and then press Enter.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Thanks for your help @Code-Apprentice

Comment: I navigated to file ->project:'name' ->project interpreter and then clicked on the plus sign on the right. I then searched and installed kivy, kivy-examples, kivy.deps.glew, kivy.deps.sdl2 and pillow. As you said I didn't have the packages installed on the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

try to install kivy from python console in pyhcharm instead windows console maybe it will work

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you! The program I tried to run however should display a label but it didn't, I will try to figure that out.

Comment: It isn't literally what you wrote but it gave me the idea.